# Price Book with 2 prices for same Product

Tags: pricebook, pricebookentry

The following query returns 2 rows for me

```
SELECT CurrencyIsoCode,Id,IsActive,IsArchived,IsDeleted,Name,Pricebook2Id,Product2Id,ProductCode,UnitPrice,UseStandardPrice FROM PricebookEntry where product2.name = 'ad14u' and pricebook2.isstandard = true
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I never knew I can have 2 prices for the same product in the same pricebook. Only difference I can see is the currency. But isn't it still duplicate? i.e. I can see from GUI one PBE with USD 200,00 (EUR 169,50) and another with EUR 500,00, so they are contradictory prices on the same PB.

Can anyone please throw any light on this? Any relevant documentation will help!

Comment: Looks like your org has the "multiple currencies" feature enabled.

Comment: Hello Derek, yes it is, but, as I mentioned in my question, doesn't that make 2 EUR prices (169.5 and 500) for same product in same price book? or is it that, as long as the CurrencyIsoCode is differing, SF will always regard these as unique rows? Is there any documentation that states this?

Comment: May be, these same product is added by 2 different user with different currency values?

Comment: If it's Yes, Please ask the users which are created are to confirm the product details..especially names?

Comment: it does, perfect @david Cheng, thanks! you can add this as answer, so other people know where to look